# MobX autorun firing just once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am learning MobX and cannot understand why `autorun` is only firing once...

```
const {observable, autorun} = mobx;
class FilterStore {
    @observable filters = {};
    @observable items = [1,2,3];
}

const store = window.store = new FilterStore;

setInterval(() => {
    store.items[0] = +new Date
}, 1000)

autorun(() => {
    console.log(store.filters);
    console.log(store.items);
    console.log('----------------');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1vmtzn27/

This is a very simple setup, and the `setInterval` is changing the value of my observable array every second but `autorun` is not fired... any idea why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mobx but I just changed `store.items[0]` with `store.items` which works. I also don't really now why you use `= +` when adding the date. Perhaps you wanted to add the date to the array in which case the syntax in `+=` with the `store.items` change.

Comment: @E.Sundin hi! The `+new Date` is a shortcut to `new Date().getTime();`, and about doing `store.items = +new Date` that will not be a array anymore...

Comment: Cool shortcut! What I meant was appending to the array (`store.items +=`) instead of just changing it's contents but I see now that this isn't a valid solution to you problem.

Comment: @E.Sundin: Just FYI, `+=` doesn't add entries to an array in JavaScript.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course! Silly me, I don't know why I assumed so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and the `setInterval` is changing the value of my observable array every second...

No, it isn't. It's changing the *contents* of the array, but not the observable MobX is watching, which is `store.items` itself. Changing *that* would look like this:

```
store.items = [+new Date];
```

Since you didn't access `store.items[0]` in the `autorun` callback, it isn't watched for changes. (`console.log` did access it, but not in a way MobX could see.)

If you *do* access `store.items[0]`, it will be watched for changes; if you add to or remove from the array, you might want to access `length` explicitly as well:

```
autorun(() => {
    store.filters;
    store.items.length;
    store.items.forEach(function() { } );
    console.log('Update received');
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vmtzn27/2/)

Comment: Hmmm.... ok, interesting! So [doing `console.log(store.items[0]);` inside the `autorun`](https://jsfiddle.net/1vmtzn27/3/) does work. Is MobX analyzing the code inside the `autorun` to avoid excessive callbacks?

Comment: @Rikard: I haven't gotten into the internals of MobX yet, but don't think that it's looking at the code (and certainly hope not). I think the issue was just that `console.log` accesses the array entries via an internal mechanism that bypasses what MobX watches for.

Comment: About my problem, you nailed it. Thank you. Now I wonder why `autorun(() => console.log(store.items));` is not called, but `autorun(() => console.log(store.items.length));` is called, even though its not changed, since `store.items[0] = +new Date` is not changing that specific property... but that's outside the scope of this question I suppose :P

Comment: Asked a question with the followup... http://stackoverflow.com/q/41087478/2427193

Comment: @Rikard: How bizarre, [replicated here](https://jsfiddle.net/1vmtzn27/5/). I have no idea. :-)