# MobX autorun behavior

Tags: javascript, mobx

I'm exploring MobX and went intrigued by a problem:

If I have this observable:

```
class ItemsStore {
    @observable items = [1,2,3];
}
const store = new ItemsStore;
```

and then change it like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    store.items[0] = +new Date
}, 1000)
```

I noticed the following:

- `autorun(() => console.log(store.items));` [never fires...](https://jsfiddle.net/f2yx2ouw/1/)
- `autorun(() => console.log(store.items[0]));` [fires every 1s and gives a new value](https://jsfiddle.net/f2yx2ouw/2/)
- `autorun(() => console.log(store.items.length));` [fires every 1s although value is unchanged](https://jsfiddle.net/f2yx2ouw/3/)

What is the API logic behind this? I would expect that since `store.items` never fires, that *unchanged properties* would behave the same.

And how come MobX knows what code is inside my callback? is it analysing my callback I pass to `autorun`?

Comment: As per the docs **not just the todos array is being observed by the autorun, but also the individual properties inside the todo items** are observed.So I guess if any item in an array is actively dispalying value or using value for any other calculation then autorun fires.Else, it won't.There is a nice explanation in the docs reagarding this..https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/getting-started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**console.log(store.items)**

An autorun is fired when the observables that were dereferenced in the last autorun are changed. `store.items` does not dereference any observables. Try `store.items.slice()` or `store.items.toJS()` to get the desired effect.

**console.log(store.items[0])**

This fired because the observable that got dereferenced is changed.

**console.log(store.items.length)**

This is run because a MobX array is not a real array. The `length` property is [**defined as follows**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/observablearray.ts#L428):

```
Object.defineProperty(ObservableArray.prototype, "length", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    get: function(): number {
        return this.$mobx.getArrayLength();
    },
    set: function(newLength: number) {
        this.$mobx.setArrayLength(newLength);
    }
});
```

`getArrayLength` [**reports that the MobX array has been observed**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/master/src/types/observablearray.ts#L116):

```
getArrayLength(): number {
    this.atom.reportObserved();
    return this.values.length;
}
```

Comment: Tack Tholle! (Thank you!)

Comment: @Rikard Det var så lite så. :)